# Exporting Flash CS5.5 project to .apk file causes all movieclips to play

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I am loading an AS2 .swf into an AS3 project. When compiling and running the project inside of flash the .swf file loads perfectly and I can play the game I am loading as I normally could. However once I export the project to a .apk file to be used on android, when I run and install the program, all movieclips that were in the loaded AS2 .swf just play continuously. Below is the code I use to load the AS2 file in the AS3 project:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

var loader:Loader=new Loader();
var _lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("trans2.swf"), _lc);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void{  
     addChild(loader.content.parent);
}
```

Comment: Mobile apps are compiled to native code, and I don't think anything about the process accommodates AS2.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason Android apps need air runtime.  It's made for as3, not as2, so Android will not understand any as2 code, and so won't apple.  Maybe later they will make it availible for as2, even though it would be a downgrade, since as3 has much more functuallity than as2.